# How to track number of calls and each call timings using selenium2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to track number of calls and each calls time of complete page load using selenium2? I have a page that calls multiple services to complete it's full load so want to track each call timings.

Comment: If you are using Firefox you may want to look at a browser debugger such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). It has a tool that lists all the calls on the page and a graph to show their timings. There is also Firebug Lite for other browsers, but I suggest looking for an alternative.

Comment: I have feelings, that your investigation has wrong direction. Instead of `sleep()` you should use Explicit or Implicit Waits http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html. Is it what are you looking for?

Comment: yes,can we get the same information what we get in FireBug or FireBug lite using selenium?

Comment: For example, my page takes 30 seconds to load.While loading a page there are multiple calls to multiple services so want to know which call takes more time.

Comment: ChromeDriver actually produces a log with all this timing information. Not sure about the other ones.

Comment: The log sounds like the best approach (+1). If not, this is a programming question rather than a Selenium one I believe. What language are you coding in? You may have to write your own profiler; does anyone have any ideas on this? I would be quite interested in the solution as well as I am looking to do this soon as well.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver at the bottom, there are instructions to get Firebug running

Answer (score 1):

You can use browsermob-proxy along with selenium2 to find the load time. It will get you the HAR file which you can feed to another tool to see the result. Read this blog by [AutomatedTester](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/blog/2012/automating-web-performance-data-collection-with-browsermob-proxy-and-selenium.html)